# Dynamically changing trait

Tags: traits, enthought, traitsui

Is it possible to have two classes

class SimulationDigitizer(HasTraits):
    width = Int(1920)
    height = Int(1080)
    name = 'Simulation'

class FileDigitizer(HasTraits):
    Filename = File
    name = 'File'

and another class 'Digitizer' having an attribute (or trait) UserDigitizer whose edition dialog will propose a drop-down list with 'Simulation' and 'File' and, depending on the choice, the instance edition of either FileDigitizer or SimulationDigitizer and get the result in UserDigitizer ?

Thanks

Comment: As in your previous question -- do you really need this to be created dynamically, or would it suffice to have one or the other *appear* to the user when needed (but actually exist invisibly all along)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonathan, you are right, the problem is to select the appropriate subcomponent among many possible.

I ended with the following code, I guess it can be improved in many ways. I am new both to Python and Traits.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, File, Enum, Instance
from traitsui.api import View, Item, Handler, HGroup, InstanceEditor

class UserComponent ( HasTraits ):
    """ An empty class from which all user component classes are
        derived.
    """
    pass

class SimulationDigitizer(UserComponent):
    width = Int(1920)
    height = Int(1080)
    nature = 'Simulation'

class FileDigitizer(UserComponent):
    filename = File
    nature = 'Reading a file'

UserDigitizers = [FileDigitizer, SimulationDigitizer]

class UserComponentHandler(Handler):    

    def __init__(self,_user_components_dict):
        Handler.__init__(self)
        self._user_components_dict = _user_components_dict

    def object_user_component_nature_changed ( self, info ):
        # Find new UserComponent class from string in user_component_nature
        new_user_component = self._user_components_dict[info.object.user_component_nature]
        # If different, change user_component value
        if info.object.user_component is not new_user_component:
            info.object.user_component = new_user_component

class Digitizer(HasTraits):
    user_component_nature = Enum([x().nature for x in UserDigitizers])
    _user_file_digitizer = FileDigitizer()
    _user_simulation_digitizer = SimulationDigitizer()

    # Dictionary with keys = nature and values = user digitizers
    _user_digitizers_dict = {x.nature: x for x in [_user_file_digitizer,_user_simulation_digitizer]}

    user_component = Enum(_user_file_digitizer,_user_simulation_digitizer)

    view = View(HGroup(Item('user_component_nature', 
                            label = 'Nature'),
                    Item('user_component',
                            show_label = False, 
                            editor = InstanceEditor(label = 'Edit', 
                                                    kind = 'modal'))),
                handler = UserComponentHandler(_user_digitizers_dict))

d = Digitizer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d.configure_traits()
```